# How to render wide color gamut (Display p3) correctly in OpenGL under IOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, gpuimage

IOS support wide color.
But when render a image in wide color, the image color is not correctly.

In EAGLLayer, there is drawableProperties which can choose the color format, but it doesn't have option to select with wide color.

Besides, I find some hint on Android [Document](https://developer.android.com/training/wide-color-gamut#opengl)

But I don't know how to implement it on IOS correctly. (Tried and failed with GPUImage framework)

So is it possible to render correct image with openGL on CAEAGLLayer? or it is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a blog say it seem not support ?

http://litherum.blogspot.com/2017/07/wide-and-deep-color-in-metal-and-opengl.html

Comment: I have read this blog, and want to find another detail information . Thanks.